# Getting error while triggering auto e-mail using script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a google spreadsheet which looks like:

```
   A             B                    C             D
1 Name        e-mail              Identifer       Status
2 Alex       ax@gmail.com         ERT ER          A
3 Micke      miike477@gmail.com   Ejyu er w       
4 John       john7788@tri.com     Arb Ed          C
```

I have a drop down list in column `D` (let say A,B & C for example), now i want that whenever the value changes (Initially the column `D` would be blank) in column `D` against a particular `Name` than an automatic e-mail trigger to e-mail id mentioned in column `B` by below mentioned sender id and content.

The email should be trigger whenever value changes in column `D` except for the blank, and if there were previously value was "B" and now it change to "C" than mail should be trigger.

Sender-example@gmail.com
CC-test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com

E-mail Body:

Hi Alex (`Should be picked from column A depending against which name e-mail trigger`)

some sentence here.
some sentence here with your **ERT ER** (`Should be pick from column C`) has status **A** (`should be pick from column D`).

Regards,
example
123456789

I am trying using below mentioned script:

```
function onEdit(event){
    if(event.range.getColumn() == 4){ //A -> 1, B -> 2, etc
        function sendMyEmail(line){
    var sendTo = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
    var cc     = 'test1@gmail.com'+","+'test2@gmail.com';
    var subject = "What is the: "+ spreadsheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
    var content = "Hi "+spreadsheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();+","

                 +"what is the vlaue "+spreadsheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();+ "with the status"+spreadsheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();+ "."
    MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo,
        cc,
        subject,
        content);
}
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Diego Missing ; before statement. (line 5, file "Code")

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) and review how you're doing the string concatenation for `cc`, `subject`, and `content.

Comment: @Diego Thanks...Now i'm getting error:`TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")`

Comment: @Diego I think i am getting that error because running the script manually in script editor, but i have tried to change the value in column D but didn't receive the e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major issues.

1. [Simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) (such as `MailApp`).
2. Your usage of `MailApp.sendEmail()` is incorrect as you're passing `cc` to where should be passed either the subject or the replyTo address ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options)). Argument order is important.

To address the issue of simple triggers, all you need to do is [install a trigger manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) that calls your function on edit.

[image]

All other issues are addressed in the code below.

```
function sendEmailToUser(event){
  var eventRange = event.range;
  var sheet = eventRange.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var column = eventRange.getColumn();
  if (sheetName == "Sheet1" && column == 4){ // Make sure the edited column is in the correct sheet, otherwise editing Column D in Sheet3 might trigger this
    var row = eventRange.getRow(); // You need to know which row so you can send the email to the correct person
    var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
    var name = rowValues[0][0];
    var sendTo = rowValues[0][1];
    var identifier = rowValues[0][2];
    var status = rowValues[0][3];
    if (status != "") { // Don't send the email if the status is blank
      var cc = "test1@example.com, test2@example.com";
      var subject = "What is the: " + identifier;
      var content = "Hi " + name + "\nWhat is the value " + identifier + " with the status " + status + "?";
      MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo, subject, content, {
        cc: cc
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much...it worked very well. Just a little help require i just want to leave space of one line between `Hi` and Next line and again between `Next` line and Regards Line. and want to bold the +identifier+ and +status+.

Comment: @VectorJX Do you see the "\n"?  That's a new line character. Add another `\n` and you'll get a blank line.

Comment: Thanks...bold option is not possible??

Comment: It is possible @VectorJX. You'll need to use the `htmlBody` advanced parameter of `sendMail`.

Comment: Means i have to create the whole e-mail body in html format??

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can i bold those two values (identifier & status) in email body. I have tried many things but couldn't succeed.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54670/send-html-email-from-a-spreadsheet-using-a-different-alias

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168478/discussion-between-vector-jx-and-diego).

Comment: @VectorJX This is a new topic. You should post a new question so that it and the answer can be available for reference to anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks...posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714667/bold-specific-word-in-email-body-while-sending-it-through-googlescript