# bold specific word in email body while sending it through googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a google spreadsheet which looks like:

```
   A             B                    C             D
1 Name        e-mail              Identifer       Status
2 Alex       ax@gmail.com         ERT ER          A
3 Micke      miike477@gmail.com   Ejyu er w       
4 John       john7788@tri.com     Arb Ed          C
```

I have a drop down list in column `D` (let say A,B & C for example), now i want that whenever the value changes (Initially the column `D` would be blank) in column `D` against a particular `Name` than an automatic e-mail trigger to e-mail id mentioned in column `B` by below mentioned sender id and content.

The email should be trigger whenever value changes in column `D` except for the blank, and if there were previously value was "B" and now it change to "C" than mail should be trigger.

Sender-example@gmail.com
CC-test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com

E-mail Body:

Hi Alex (`Should be picked from column A depending against which name e-mail trigger`)

some sentence here.
some sentence here with your **ERT ER** (`Should be pick from column C`) has status **A** (`should be pick from column D`).

Regards,
example
123456789

I am trying using below mentioned script (which is working fine just want to bold value of `identifier` and `status` in e-mail body):

```
    function sendEmailToUser(event){
  var eventRange = event.range;
  var sheet = eventRange.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var column = eventRange.getColumn();
  if (sheetName == "Sheet1" && column == 4){ // Make sure the edited column is in the correct sheet, otherwise editing Column D in Sheet3 might trigger this
    var row = eventRange.getRow(); // You need to know which row so you can send the email to the correct person
    var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
    var name = rowValues[0][0];
    var sendTo = rowValues[0][1];
    var identifier = rowValues[0][2];
    var status = rowValues[0][3];
    if (status != "") { // Don't send the email if the status is blank
      var cc = "test1@example.com, test2@example.com";
      var subject = "What is the: " + identifier;
      var content = "Hi " + name + "\nWhat is the value " + identifier + " with the status " + status + "?";
      MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo, subject, content, {
        cc: cc
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you review and try to apply this? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54670/send-html-email-from-a-spreadsheet-using-a-different-alias

Comment: The only way to get what you want it to use HTML optional body. Text body cannot be formatted.

Comment: @Diego Yes...but `identifer` and `Status` are fetched values they are not getting formatted.

Comment: @VectorJX Please show in your code how you're trying to format it

Comment: @Diego I am trying something like:`var content = '<body>' "Hi " + name + 
                    '<p> '"\nWhat is the value "'<b>' + identifier + </b> " with the status "'<b>' + status +'</b>' "?"</body>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up your single and double quotes and also not concatenating them correctly. Please review [Javascript Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp).

To concatenate `'<body>` and `"Hi"`, you need to include the `+` operator as they're two separate strings:

```
'<body>' + "Hi"
```

**BUT**, the concatenation of `'<body>'` and `"Hi"` is unnecessary when you can simply write it as

```
"<body>Hi"
```

This is what you should be doing:

```
var content = "Hi " + name + "\nWhat is the value " + identifier + " with the status " + status + "?";
var contentHTML = "<body><p>Hi " + name + "</p><br><p>What is the value <b>" + identifier + "</b> with the status <b>" + status + "</b>?</p></body>";
MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo, subject, content, {
  cc: cc,
  htmlBody: contentHTML
});
```

`content` Will display the plain-text (unformatted) text for those users whose email clients (or by personal preference) do not display HTML email. `contentHTML` is the same, but shows the HTML formatted content.